# Number of writes in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, statistics, monitoring

Is there a view to get statistics about the number of writes per day in an Oracle database, and the amount of data associated ?
I had a view over these : V$METRIC_HISTORY, V$METRIC, but I did not find something so relevant about that.

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at  [`DBA_HIST_FILESTATXS` view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/DBA_HIST_FILESTATXS.html#GUID-2A369264-D4AF-4BE4-B33C-76888DDCDD9D) :

> `DBA_HIST_FILESTATXS` displays information about file read/write statistics. This view contains snapshots of `V$FILESTAT`.

Following columns should be of interest for you :

- `PHYWRTS` : Number of times DBWR is required to write
- `PHYBLKWRT` : Number of blocks written to disk, which may be the same as `PHYWRTS` if all writes are single blocks

Note :

- if you want to know the *volume* written, you need to multiply `PHYBLKWRT` with `BLOCK_SIZE`
- if you want to filter by dates, you have to `JOIN` with view `dba_hist_snapshot`, that stores the snapshot history

Comment: Allright thanks, I had a look on this view but a select does not return anything, do these snapshots have to be set somewhere to exploit this view ?

Comment: @Anthony : mm, do you have something in `V$$FILESTAT` ? And in `dba_hist_snapshot` ?

Comment: Yes I have something on both of these views you quoted, however I get nothing in DBA_HIST_FILESTATXS (no records)

Comment: You *might* need to enable the `timed_statistics` parameter, like : `alter system set timed_statistics=true;`